# Can this be an actual patent?

Tags: prior-art-request, patentability

In reference to the patent: [US6546397](https://www.google.com/patents/US6546397)

This patent appears overly broad. Basically, it is saying anyone who creates a website that utilizes a database and a backend interface is infringing. I can think of many open source tools that fall in this category - wordpress for one. Any organization that has a website that utilizes a database and a backend editor, including companies like Facebook, Amazon, Apple, EBay, etc would all be infringing if this were an enforceable patent. This makes no sense.

Comment: The subject matter that can be infringed is described in the claims. From what I was able to understand, it claims a solution to execute programming languages, such as C++ or Visual Basic, in a web browser. Step a) in claim 1 seems narrow...

Comment: change question to prior art request,

Answer (score 1):

That's not what it says. The broadest claimed subject matter is that of claim 1:

1. A method to allow users to produce Internet websites on and for computers having a browser and a virtual machine capable of generating displays, said method comprising:
   (a) presenting a viewable menu having a user selectable panel of settings describing elements on a website, said panel of settings being presented through a browser on a computer adapted to accept one or more of said selectable settings in said panel as inputs therefrom, and where at least one of said user selectable settings in said panel corresponds to commands to said virtual machine;
   (b) generating a display in accordance with one or more user selected settings substantially contemporaneously with the selection thereof;
   (c) storing information representative of said one or more user selected settings in a database;
   (d) generating a website at least in part by retrieving said information representative of said one or more user selected settings stored in said database; and
   (e) building one or more web pages to generate said website from at least a portion of said database and at least one run time file, where said at least one run time file utilizes information stored in said database to generate virtual machine commands for the display of at least a portion of said one or more web pages.

Unless the example organizations perform each of these steps in substantially the same detailed ways, there is no infringement.

Comment: I think that's what making a website using any sort of content management system is. Something like Wordpress ( free, open source and available for commercial use) provides users with a viewable menu with a selectable panel of settings. A user would select and it would send a command, like create a new page. Then you type in your text and add your images. Wordpress (and all systems like it) contain a database where this information is stored. The front-end or what people see, is based on what is stored in that database. This site on stack exchange uses the same principle. What am I missing?

Comment: Does Wordpress use a virtual machine backend? Does it use a run time file to generate virtual machine commands corresponding to the selectable settings?

Comment: WordPress is written in the interpreted language PHP so yes, it does run in a virtual machine. Not sure about the second point, but I would be very surprised if none of the CMS' created some amount of interpreted code dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what making a website using any sort of content management system is. Something like Wordpress (completely free and open source and available for commercial use) provides users with a viewable menu with a selectable panel of settings. A user would select and it would send a command, like create a new page. Then you type in your text and add your images. Wordpress (and all systems like it) contain a database where this information is stored. The front-end or what people see, is based on what is stored in that database. This site on stack exchange uses the same principle. So does Amazon, EBay, Google, etc. They all would function this way.

Maybe I'm missing something but this appears to claim that unless you just build a website in pure html with no content management system, you are infringing. And 99% of all websites now are built with a content management system of some sort that all function within this framework.